Storing and retrieving a decimal from TempData
I want to store a decimal in TempData. I read in the documentation that it's not possible to store a decimal, the same way you can store an int for example. I've tried every possible combination of storing and retrieving, but the error is always the same - "The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Infrastructure.DefaultTempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type 'System. Decimal'.".
TempData["PromocodeDiscount"] = 5.00;

 decimal discount = 0;
 if (TempData["PromocodeDiscount"] != null)
 {
     discount = Convert.ToDecimal(TempData["PromocodeDiscount"]);
 }


TempData uses JSON serialization by default, and the default serializer doesn't handle decimal types as you discovered.  One thing you could try if its not too big a deal if store the value as a string instead and just convert it before you use it again.

You could try below code to implement your requirement
HomeController:
public IActionResult Index()
{
 
    // Store a decimal value in TempData as a string
    decimal decimalValue = 123.45m;
    TempData["DecimalValue"] = decimalValue.ToString();

    return RedirectToAction("test");

}
public IActionResult test()
{
    //Retrieve the decimal value from TempData
    if (TempData["DecimalValue"] != null)
    {
        string decimalString = TempData["DecimalValue"].ToString();
        if (decimal.TryParse(decimalString, out decimal decimalValue))
        {
            ViewBag.DecimalValue = decimalValue;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.DecimalValue = "Error: Could not convert TempData value to decimal.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.DecimalValue = "No value found in TempData.";
    }

    return View();
}

View:
<h2>Decimal Value from TempData</h2>

<p>@ViewBag.DecimalValue</p>

Result:

